# Is the LWJGL Keyboard.isKeyDown Method Relitive To The Update?

Tags: java, input, keyboard, lwjgl

If I held down the keys *up* and *down*, and pressed a button that calls *Display.update* and ran the following code:

```
 while (!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE);
     Display.update();
 boolean up = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 boolean down = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN);
 if (up && down)
     System.out.println("Both keys detected");
```

What would be the outcome? I'm not sure if I should check for all the keys at once during the game update or just when I need them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question at all but ill try to answer. I have no idea how or where you update your keys, but if you update your key listener, then your program will check if the booleans are true or false. I think you need to learn some basic java before going on to OpenGL because this is a question someone with less than a couple weeks of coding experience would ask. Also, its relative not relitive.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not relative to Display.update as it is not logical to hold all the booleans for the keys and update the every half a millisecond.

there for i say it is independant of Display.Update